# Exercises about cardinality of sets

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Cardinality of both following sets are $3^n$, but I can not understand how:

$$ {\{(S,T) \mid S \in \mathcal{P}(A),\, T \in \mathcal{P}(A),\, S \cap T = \emptyset\}}$$
$$ {\{(S,T) \mid S \in \mathcal{P}(A),\, T \in \mathcal{P}(A),\, S \cup T = A\}}$$

$\mathcal{P}$ indicates **power set** and $A = \{1,2,3, \dots ,n\}$.
I really appreciate if anyone can answer my question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first set,
\begin{align}
{\{(S,T) | S \in P(A), T \in P(A), S \cap T = \oslash\}} &= {\{(S,T) | S \in P(A), T \subset S^c\}} \\
&= \bigcup_{S \subset A} \bigcup_{T \subset S^c} {\{ (S,T) \}}
\end{align}
where the two unions are disjoint so the cardinal of this set is
$$ \sum_{S \subset A}\sum_{T \subset S^c}1= \sum_{S \subset A} 2^{n-card(A)}=2^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^k = 3^n.$$
For the second set it is the same idea :
\begin{align}
{\{(S,T) | S \in P(A), T \in P(A), S \cup T = A\}} &= {\{(S,T) | S \in P(A), A\setminus S \subset T\}} \\
&= \bigcup_{S \subset A} ~~ \bigcup_{T:A \setminus S \subset T}~~ {\{(S,T)\}}
\end{align}
and for the cardinal,
$$ \sum_{S \subset A} ~~\sum_{T: A\setminus S \subset T}~~1= \sum_{S \subset A} 2^{card(S)} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}2^k=3^n.$$

Comment: That's great. Thanks for your comprehensive answer.